# How to search an antd table onChange without closing input box with confirm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onchange, antd

AntD has a couple of examples for how to search a table with their event handlers, but they use buttons for confirm and reset which are too clunky in my context.  I need to be able to search onchange, so that when they remove the filter, it removes the search.  I have changed the sample to remove the buttons, and added the `handleSearch` handler to the onChange listener.

however.

There is this stupid `confirm` function that is not defined anywhere, and it is closing the search dialogue every keystroke.  If I comment it out, it never actually filters the table.  If I leave it in, I can only search one letter at a time.

How do I modify my code so that it filters the column on change, but leaves the search input open for further input?

Data:

```
const data = [
    {
        key: '1',
        name: 'John Brown',
        age: 32,
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '2',
        name: 'Joe Black',
        age: 42,
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '3',
        name: 'Jim Green',
        age: 32,
        address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '4',
        name: 'Jim Red',
        age: 32,
        address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    },
];
```

Handlers:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchText: '',
        searchedColumn: '',
    };
}

handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    **confirm();//This function is not defined in code anywhere where I can edit.**
    this.setState({
        searchText: selectedKeys[0],
        searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
};

getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm }) => (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
            <Input
                ref={node => {
                    this.searchInput = node;
                }}
                placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
                value={selectedKeys[0]}
                onChange={e => {
                    setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : []);
                    this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex);
                }
                }
                style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
            />
        </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
        record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
        if (visible) {
            setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
        }
    },
    render: text =>
        this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
            <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
                searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
                autoEscape
                textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            />
        ) : (
                text
            ),
});
```

Render:

```
    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            key: 'name',
            width: '30%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
        },
        {
            title: 'Age',
            dataIndex: 'age',
            key: 'age',
            width: '20%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('age'),
        },
        {
            title: 'Address',
            dataIndex: 'address',
            key: 'address',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('address'),
        },
    ];

return (
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
        );
```

EDIT:  Screenshot showing behavior without the confirm method.  Sidney should disappear.

[image: Incorrect filter behavior]

Answer (score 2):

That is really simple.
Just do below change:

```
confirm()   
↓
confirm({ closeDropdown: false })
```

By doing so, you will be able to overwrite the filterDropdown Interface props in antd/lib/table lib, in which controls the behavior of this function.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem

remove `confirm();` from `handleSearch` function and then search working without closing search dropdown.

**Edit:**

to achieve this, you should handle data filtering yourself. create state variable `filteredData` and `isFiltered` and filter data manually.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem.  If I remove confirm, then it doesn't actually filter the table.  It just hightlights the matches.  I have added a screenshot to show what happens without confirm to my post.